# HTTPS rewrite rules too many redirects

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, url-rewriting

i just installed SSL and certificates on my vps , now i made test so fare everthings works fine on testing single html file with SSL appearing

but when i use my htacess on my website it's totally different thing iam trying to secure login.php but i got too many redirect on , pls need ur help guys

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.+).html$ $1/?%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^index/$ place/Place.php

RewriteRule ^login/$ login.php

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond $1 ^(login) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`
```

---

Thanks for replay , it still showing 301 too many redirects , basicaly if i remove the line

```
RewriteRule ^login/$ login.php
```

and keep my old code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond $1 ^(login) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

https will show but i get The requested URL /login/ was not found on this server?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+).html$ $1/?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteRule ^index/$ place/Place.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/login/?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^login/?$ login.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/login/?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/login [L,R=301]
```

Do exactly what is put here.

Comment: it redirect to login but without https now ??? , thanks a lot for your efforts

Comment: @gool55 my bad: `RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/login [L,R=301]` check the updated answer.

Comment: the login works but not in https just normal login.html, iam scratching my head over this since few days , isnt 

  'RewriteRule ^(.+).html$ $1/?%{QUERY_STRING}'  that crating the problem?

Comment: @gool55 what are your file names? is it `login.html` or `login.php`. did you try the above modified code?

Comment: my files are login.php , but showing on browser as login.html , yes tried it , it redirect to login but without https

Comment: try this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/login\.php$ [NC]`. It should work. Have updated in answer as well.

Comment: sorry it shows The requested URL /login/ was not found on this server

Comment: @gool55 Do exactly what is updated in the answer.

Comment: here is The update : i copied all the code as it is  i got  The requested URL /index/ was not found on this server